# When attempting to disable permissions for an application that is running in the background,I Have Observed that Crash is Happening

Tags: permissions, android-permissions, disable

Upon granting permissions for an application to access media and storage on a device, an issue appears when the application is minimized and the user subsequently attempts to disable said permissions. Specifically, when the user reopens the application that was running in the background, it crashes unexpectedly.

I expect the desired behavior to occur when attempting to open an application running in the background.

I expect that when I minimize an application and subsequently disable its permissions, and then return to the application while it is still running in the background, a permission popup screen should appear. This will enable me to re-enable the previously disabled permissions, allowing me to continue using the application without issue.

Tried:

As I am currently unsure of the root cause of the unexpected behavior with the permissions in question, I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance that can be offered to help diagnose and resolve this issue.

My Expectations:

I expect that when I minimize an application and subsequently disable its permissions, and then return to the application while it is still running in the background, a permission popup screen should appear. This will enable me to re-enable the previously disabled permissions, allowing me to continue using the application without issue.